# Listing available fonts in PHP

Tags: php, fonts

I'd like to query what fonts are available on a *nix-like system, ideally using PHP 5.2 or 5.3, but there doesn't seem to be many libraries available to do it in a system-independent way. [php-font-lib](https://code.google.com/p/php-font-lib/) just scans a directory ([code](https://code.google.com/p/php-font-lib/source/browse/trunk/www/font_list.php), [demo](http://pxd.me/php-font-lib/www/font_explorer.html)) but I'd hope there is a more elegant way to do it. (In any case, scanning a folder is only part of the task; font files still need to be opened to retrieve name and other metadata).

Background: I am rendering PDFs on a webserver using Inkscape, and would like to determine what fonts are available to render text elements. I'm developing on OS 10.6.8 and deploying on Linux.

Edit: I've found a [PHP wrapper](https://github.com/mgdm/php-pango) for Pango, which is an advanced font renderer often used with Cairo; both of these are used in Inkscape. The wrapper is quite new, so I am not yet sure whether it can produce a font listing - but it does look interesting `:)`.

Comment: for opening fontfiles and reading name/metadata, you can use fontforge library.

Comment: Ah, I guess you mean [programmatically](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/scripting.html)? Thanks, I've not heard of that application; I will give it a go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heh! I do an hour or so of searching, and find nothing satisfying; then like buses, several answers are found at once. Here's another method, from ImageMagick's `convert -list font` command (apparently renamed from `convert -list type` prior to v6.3.5-7 [[source](http://www.rubblewebs.co.uk/imagemagick/server/fonts.php)]). I think I prefer this over `fc-list`, as the output looks like it could be parsed as YAML.

From Linux:

```
Path: /usr/lib/ImageMagick-6.5.7/config/type-ghostscript.xml
    Font: AvantGarde-Book
        family: AvantGarde
        style: Normal
        stretch: Normal
        weight: 400
        glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/a010013l.pfb
    Font: AvantGarde-BookOblique
        family: AvantGarde
        style: Oblique
        stretch: Normal
        weight: 400
        glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/a010033l.pfb
...
```

And from the Mac:

```
Path: /opt/local/etc/ImageMagick/type-ghostscript.xml
    Font: AvantGarde-Book
        family: AvantGarde
        style: Normal
        stretch: Normal
        weight: 400
        glyphs: /opt/local/share/fonts/urw-fonts/a010013l.pfb
    Font: AvantGarde-BookOblique
        family: AvantGarde
        style: Oblique
        stretch: Normal
        weight: 400
        glyphs: /opt/local/share/fonts/urw-fonts/a010033l.pfb
...
Path: System Fonts
    Font: .Aqua-Kana-Bold
        family: .Aqua Kana
        style: Normal
        stretch: Normal
        weight: 600
        glyphs: /System/Library/Fonts/AquaKana.ttc
    Font: .Aqua-Kana-Regular
        family: .Aqua Kana
        style: Normal
        stretch: Normal
        weight: 300
        glyphs: /System/Library/Fonts/AquaKana.ttc
```

Comment: As of today I've made this my accepted answer instead of the Imagick approach, as thos provides family name information as well as the font name. My use case sometimes encounters documents with just the family name specified, which would be good to detect!

Answer (score 8):

This also yields results, although it just gets the font name as per the `Font:` line from `convert` output:

```
<?php
    $imagick = new Imagick();
    $fonts = $imagick->queryFonts();
    foreach($fonts as $font)
    {
        echo $font;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

I've just found a cross-platform command, `fc-list`. Works on OS X 10.6.8 and my Ubuntu VPS, and could easily be invoked by PHP. On my Linux machine I get a list in this format:

```
Nimbus Sans L:style=Regular Italic
URW Palladio L:style=Roman
Century Schoolbook L:style=Bold Italic
Nimbus Sans L:style=Bold
URW Chancery L:style=Medium Italic
Nimbus Roman No9 L:style=Regular
Century Schoolbook L:style=Bold
Century Schoolbook L:style=Italic
Nimbus Sans L:style=Regular
URW Palladio L:style=Italic
Nimbus Sans L:style=Bold Condensed
URW Gothic L:style=Demi
Nimbus Roman No9 L:style=Medium Italic
Nimbus Mono L:style=Bold Oblique
Dingbats:style=Regular
...continues...
```

On the Mac it looks like this:

```
URW Gothic L:style=Book Oblique
Fixed:style=ja
URW Palladio L:style=Bold Italic
Heiti SC,黑體\-簡,黒体\-簡,Heiti\-간체,黑体\-简:style=Light,細體,Mager,Fein,Ohut,Fin,Leggero,ライト,가는체,Licht,Tynn,Leve,Светлый,细体,Fina
Arial Narrow:style=Bold Italic,Negreta cursiva,tučné kurzíva,fed kursiv,Fett Kursiv,Έντονα Πλάγια,Negrita Cursiva,Lihavoitu Kursivoi,Gras Italique,Félkövér dőlt,Grassetto Corsivo,Vet Cursief,Halvfet Kursiv,Pogrubiona kursywa,Negrito Itálico,Полужирный Курсив,Tučná kurzíva,Fet Kursiv,Kalın İtalik,Krepko poševno,Lodi etzana
Fixed:style=Regular
Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
Arial:style=Bold,Negreta,tučné,fed,Fett,Έντονα,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,Полужирный,Fet,Kalın,Krepko,đậm,Lodia
KufiStandardGK:style=Regular,標準體,Ordinær,Normal,Normaali,Regolare,レギュラー,일반체,Regulier,Обычный,常规体
Courier:style=Regular,標準體,Ordinær,Normal,Normaali,Regolare,レギュラー,일반체,Regulier,Обычный,常规体
New Century Schoolbook:style=Italic
Menlo:style=Bold
Luxi Sans:style=Bold Oblique
...
```