# Display fonts on website

Tags: php, javascript, css, actionscript, fonts

The Setup:
I'm currently using getFontList() via Flash/Actionscript to get a users local font list. I am trying to display the fonts, but I want the font to appear as the font.

So I created a simple foreach that sets an inline style for font-family:[font name here]. The problem is that the displayed font name and the system-accessible font name are not the same in many cases. The fonts display name may be "My Font" but it's actual name is "MyFont" so using font-family:"My Font" doesn't work.

I can get around some of these issues just by parsing the list with PHP, removing spaces, using dashes, etc to try to get the desired result but theres some fonts with odd names or variations that my parsing game just cannot account for.

The Question:
So I said all that to ask this: Is anyone aware of a way to get around this or have a better way of making sure I'm using the correct font name variation for this to work?

Comment: I've had this problem, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749970/listing-available-fonts-in-php). I'm using `convert -list font`, as it gives plenty of info. Welcome to StackOverflow, btw.

Comment: If you get the font list already via actionscript, why don't you display the fonts via actionscript / flash as well? See as well http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to set an @font-face type to set fonts to a page. 
Official the [@font-face is CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-rule) but IE supports this since IE4, Firefox since 3.5, safari since 3.1 etc.

Note that your font has to be OTF or TTF.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p.normal {font-style:normal;}
p.italic {font-style:italic;}
p.oblique {font-style:oblique;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p class="normal">This is a paragraph, normal.</p>
<p class="italic">This is a paragraph, italic.</p>
<p class="oblique">This is a paragraph, oblique.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_font-style

Comment: When providing code that solves the problem, it is best to also give at least a short explanation of how it works so that folks reading won't have to mentally parse it line by line to understand the differences.